# Get value from input and store it to the object Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, client, local-storage

How I can get value from input and store it to the object? 
When button is clicked value from the input - should to be stored in the object. 
Thank you a lot in advance

```js
var testObject = { 'name': nameOfbook.value, 
                    'author': nameOfauthor.value, 
                    'year': year.value
                };
console.log(testObject);
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="nameOfbook" required="" placeholder="Book name" />
    <input type="text" id="nameOfauthor" required="" placeholder="Athor name" />
    <input type="text" id="year" required="" placeholder="Add year" />

   <button id="addder" type="button">StoreEmail</button>
```

Comment: You would need to get the element by ID. So use `document.getElementById`.

Comment: At least show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working JSfiddle for you.

The relevant JS code is here. Using the `id` tags on your html elements, I got all of the elements and stored them into variables. Next, I added an event listener on your button, and on click, I push the relevant `value` of each element into your `testObject`.

```
var testObject = [];

const button = document.getElementById("addder");

const name = document.getElementById("nameOfbook");
const author = document.getElementById("nameOfauthor");
const year = document.getElementById("year");


button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  testObject.push({
    name: name.value,
    author: author.value,
    year: year.value
  })
  console.log(testObject)
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/991jqomq/

Comment: Careful with the variable name `name` in a global scope.

Comment: Yes, now I have some problem with this variable name `name`. Would you be so kind to tell me any solutions? @xufox

Comment: @NazariyMural Have you done some research before asking this? You already know that there might be a problem with `name` in the global scope. The next step would be to research about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it

```
HTML: 

 <form id="new-post">
            <label for="post-title">Title:</label>
            <input id="post-title" type="text" />
            <label for="post-body">Body:</label>
            <textarea id="post-body"></textarea>
            <button>Post</button>
  </form>
```

```
JS: 

document.getElementById("new-post").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const postTitle = document.getElementById("post-title").value
    const postBody = document.getElementById("post-body").value
    const data = {
        title: postTitle,
        body: postBody
    }
    console.log(data)
})
```